# How to show progress dialog in two activity when switch from one activity to Another

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

In my android application, first activity calls REST API to get the list of items using credentials. Now on clicking on any item, item id is passed and second activity is called using intent. This second activity calls the REST API using passing id and shows the list of sub items for that id.

I am using Progress Dialog in first activity. This is working fine. I want this progress dialog also continue in the second activity until sub item list does not display.

Presently progress dialog disappear as the second activity start and a blank screen appears until the sub list does not fetch.

**Can anybody guide me how can I continue progress dialog in second activity and dismiss when sub list appears.**

Comment: you better show dialog on onCreate on second activity

Comment: and dismiss after setting adapter for the list in second activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options you can use:

1. You can stop the dialog when the first `Activity` is dismissed and then show it again in the `onCreate` method on your second `Activity`. As AkashG mentioned in the comments.
2. If you really want the dialog to be shown during the transition to the second `Activity`, you can use one single `Activity` instead of two and change the layout of that `Activity` to use the layout of the second `Activity` instead of calling another `Activity`. However, this can be complicated since you will implement the features of your two `Activities` into a single one.

Answer (score 2):

This is a hack:

In ActivityA.java declare the ProgressDialog pd as static

```
public static ProgressDialog pd;
```

In ActivityB.java use the static reference to `ActivityA.pd` and then use the below code.

```
if (ActivityA.pd != null) {
            if (ActivityA.pd.isShowing()) {
                ActivityA.pd.dismiss();
            }
            else {
                Log.e(Vars.TAG, "It is NOT SHOWING");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You shoud use AsyncTask

```
class FetchTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>
{
    ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
         super.onPreExecute();
         progress=ProgressDialog.show(Context, "", "Loading...");
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
    {

        // fetch your data here 

         return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Then you can execute this task in your `onCreate` as

```
new FetchTask().execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only solution to your answer-show dialog on onCreate on second activity

As you said - progress dialog disappear as the second activity start and a blank screen appears until the sub list does not fetch.the solution can be as dismiss the dialog when the data in list sets completely i mean after setting adapter to the list you can dismiss dialog and it wont show blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use fragments in your case (with support library if needed).
Then you change this two activities to fragments and create showProgressDialog and hideProgressDialog methods on (parent) activity.
Progress dialog will be always visible, because it's in the same activity, but fragments will have completly separated logic, same as activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having it as 2 activities. Best way will be to have the progress dialog in your second activity as well.Because as soon as your second activity starts, the first activity goes to the background.You cannot expect the progress dialog of the first activity to be still visible as it has moved to back.Best way is to have a progress dialog in your second activity and show when you are trying to retrieve your sublist. dismiss the progress dialog after getting the sublist UI populated.